# How to make a small zinc-air battery?

Tags: electrochemistry

**Background**:
I want to make a *very* small (20-30mg, 3 x 3 x 1 mm) primary battery cell, for powering a device that will go on a bumblebee. It will only need a capacity of about 300μWh (~1J). I'll need a peak current of about 2.5mA (although this is 'negotiable'). Ideally it needs to provide 1.8V - 3.3V (but obviously can place in series, to get voltage up).

**Plan**:
I thought a zinc-air battery would be ideal, as it only needs to be a primary cell; high energy density; simple (so easy to make and miniaturise); doesn't require complicated equipment.
Following a fairly standard approach: the initial version will just be sandwich of zinc foil (anode, ~20μm thick), copper foil (catalyst & negative terminal, ~10um thick), and sodium hydroxide as the electrolyte.

I need a separator and a semipermeable enclosure...

**Question 1**: For the separator, would a standard PE Battery Separator work? (I don't want something that will dissolve or react with the hydroxides). I think this is what is used in li-ion batteries (needs to be something I can buy).

**Question 2**: At least some of the enclosure needs to be oxygen permeable - what material should I consider (to keep hydroxides in, but allow ingress of oxygen)? (ideally not too exotic - need something I can actually buy!).

**Question 3**: What modifications would you suggest to make this more capacious or powerful? (e.g. I wonder about replacing the zinc foil with zinc powder suspended in an electrolyte gel, to increase surface area, for example). I guess I could switch to a dual-electrolyte battery - but I'm trying to keep it simple (especially given how small it is). I also wonder about whether increasing the surface area of the 'cathode' catalyst?

**Question 4**: Feel free to answer with wider suggestions of other chemistries that I might consider that are similarly simple, and easy to build/use.

Comment: On a bumblebee ?

Comment: A SR4165w / 337 cell weighs ~100 mg (https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Seiko-Instruments/SR416SW?qs=wUXugUrL1qxKS1AC4Wuieg%3D%3D) and is ~5 mm dia x 1.65 mm. Perhaps removing most of the metal shell could bring it down to fly-weight?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I'm currently about to use this 70mg battery (https://www.sii.co.jp/en/me/datasheets/ms-rechargeable/ms412fe-5/). As you've spotted, the metal case is a large part of the weight (also the discharge rate means I'll need to combine it with a 100uF cap probably). Yours is a good suggestion: I've considered modifying these batteries before, but not tried it. Maybe lithium batteries aren't a good start for that (they won't like oxygen getting in).

Comment: @Maurice: I'm putting a bluetooth (BLE) SoC on the bee: It receives and stores packets [and received signal strength] sent by high-gain, rotating, bluetooth transmitters. Reading off this data later, we can triangulate the path the bee took.

Comment: BTW, would a passive corner reflector work, triangulated by multiple light-sources and cameras? It would need to be NIR or visible light, though, due to size limit, limiting tracking to line-of-sight, and blocked by foliage. *sigh*

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - yes! [Here's our paper about it](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.13699). We've also done as you described, with 6 camera systems arranged around the nest & reconstructed the 3d path of the bee during learning flights. Unfortunately the signal strength suffers from the radar equation's 1/d^4 which means that beyond about 30-40m the signal is very hard to detect over false positives. I'm finding low energy bluetooth (esp with the high-gain antenna on the transmitter) has a range of 100s of metres (if there's not too much in the way).

Comment: @lionfish, congrats on that fine paper, and thank you for forwarding the link! Best wishes on the "RFID tags". Hmmmm... charge from a piezo transducer when they flap wings? ;-) Just kidding.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik That's been done: [piezo tranducer to get power from bees paper](https://research.bangor.ac.uk/portal/files/22735020/08439173.pdf) - a few uW though - so I think a 1mm^2 solar cell would probably be more use!

On topic: I've ordered a Celgard single layer PP diaphragm (2500) as a separator, some zinc foil, copper foil and stainless steel foil [I couldn't easily find pure iron foil] and some NaOH. Will report back what works. I've not solved what semi-permeable membrane to use - so any advice on that would be really appreciated.